# Microsoft CRM 2013- Bulk editing team security roles across business units

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, security-roles

My client has a three tier organizational model, with 184 total business units.  I imported the business units from file, which created a default team for each business unit.  Unfortunately these teams by default have no user roles and cannot be assigned ownership of entities.

My next move was to select all of my teams and do a bulk "Manage Roles" to set all teams to have a user role of Customer Service Rep.  This results in a warning that "You have selected users from different business units.  Users cannot be assigned roles from business units outside their own, so only the selected roles from each user's business unit will be assigned."  In essence, this means that if I bulk edit roles, I will need to select 184 roles, one instance of the Customer Service Rep role for each business unit.

This seems remarkably stupid, since there is in fact only one Customer Service Rep role that to my knowledge behaves identically across all 184 business units.  I am looking for insight into why the bulk role editing behaves this way, as well as a solution for assigning all of my business units the desired role.

Thanks!

Comment: Every Security Role you create (or that already exists) will create a copy in every child Business Unit, and so on down the hierarchy. So in your scenario there are 184 copies of the Customer Service Rep role with different GUIDs. they are all identical, and you can only edit the one at the top and the rest are kept in synch.

Comment: Interesting, this is unintuitive, but there must be some reason why it was implemented this way.